# Token Authentication vs. Cookies

Tags: authentication, cookies, ember.js

What is the difference between token authentication and authentication using cookies?

I am trying to implement the [Ember Auth Rails Demo](https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth-rails-demo/wiki) but I do not understand the reasons behind using token authentication as described in the [Ember Auth FAQ](https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth/wiki/FAQ) on the question "Why token authentication?"

Comment: A Token can be given to your mobile app and stored in a variable (by you) for later use or saved (by you) via JavaScript in your browser for use in SPA requests. A Cookie is generally used in a browser (by the browser).

Comment: See article  https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/ written in 2016.

Comment: Cookie itself cannot do authentication. It's done by store token inside cookie.

Comment: i think your doubt will be cleared here [link](https://roadmap.sh/guides/token-authentication)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A typical web app is mostly **stateless**, because of its **request/response** nature. The HTTP protocol is the best example of a **stateless** protocol. But since most web apps need **state**, in order to hold the **state** between server and client, cookies are used such that the server can send a cookie in every response back to the client. This means the next request made from the client will include this cookie and will thus be recognized by the server. This way the server can maintain a **session** with the **stateless** client, knowing mostly everything about the app's **state**, but stored in the server. In this scenario at no moment does the client hold **state**, which is not how [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com) works.

In Ember.js things are different. Ember.js makes the programmer's job easier because it holds indeed the **state** for you, in the client, knowing at every moment about its **state** without having to make a request to the server asking for **state** data.

However, holding **state** in the client can also sometimes introduce concurrency issues that are simply not present in **stateless** situations. Ember.js, however, deals also with these issues for you; specifically ember-data is built with this in mind. In conclusion, Ember.js is a framework designed for **stateful** clients.

Ember.js does not work like a typical **stateless** web app where the **session**, the **state** and the corresponding cookies are handled almost completely by the server. Ember.js holds its **state** completely in Javascript (in the client's memory, and not in the DOM like some other frameworks) and does not need the server to manage the session. This results in Ember.js being more versatile in many situations, e.g. when your app is in offline mode.

Obviously, for security reasons, it does need some kind of **token** or **unique key** to be sent to the server everytime a request is made in order to be **authenticated**. This way the server can look up the send token (which was initially issued by the server) and verify if it's valid before sending a response back to the client.

In my opinion, the main reason why to use an authentication token instead of cookies as stated in [Ember Auth FAQ](https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth/wiki/FAQ) is primarily because of the nature of the Ember.js framework and also because it fits more with the **stateful** web app paradigm. Therefore the cookie mechanism is not the best approach when building an Ember.js app.

I hope my answer will give more meaning to your question.

Comment: I still don't understand why a token is better/different than a cookie. One way or another you are sending something to the api server that identifies a valid session. Assuming you are running everything on a single domain (and even if ember and your api are on different servers all you have to do to accomplish this is run behind a cdn, which you should probably do anyway) what advantage do tokens offer that warrants the extra setup work and extra susceptibility to timing attacks?

Comment: Agreed with Michael Johnston. This answer keeps explaining what token-based authentication is but actually did not answer the question. The closest relevant info I can see is in the last bit _"because of the nature of the ember.js framework and also because it fits more with the statefull web app paradigm"_ but that's not much of an answer at all. I have the same question.

Comment: I agree with both of the comments here... In fact, I feel that whole "it's the ember way" is a bit of a cop-out

Comment: I honestly think statefulness is a red herring in regards to cookie vs. a token submitted via other means.  I think it conflates the notions of user evidence with other user profile information.  I could use a cookie just the same as an HTTP header or other channel for submitting a token.  I think the difference is more about sidestepping issues related to single origin policy for cookies or taking away the burden of implementing a cookie container from native clients of your back end.

Comment: After reading more about JSON Web Tokens (https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token-32) I'd guess that these folks are specifically talking about tokens whose authenticity is assured by having the server sign them, removing the need to track any data whatsoever on the server side for their verification.  I imagine this could be delivered as the contents of a cookie, but that is not the direction people are generally going with this approach, and suffers from the usual complications of working with cookies.

Comment: I think comparing cookies to tokens is like comparing apples to pears. Cookies are a transport mechanism which could of course be used to transfer a token. Another transport mechanism is for example the authorization-header. The more related discussion is client-side stored state vs server-side stored state, I think.

Comment: don't advertise ember.js focus on the question asked.. sorry to be rude.

Comment: Why have you written state in bold, every time? It's really distracting.

Comment: Not an expert, and oversimplifying: The cookie(~stateful) VS token(~stateless) auth is a bit tangled up: Both usually use cookies and both have a state. But cookie auth has the state in a session on a server (bad if you want to scale with many servers) and is more or less sending the session id via cookie. Token auth sends a token via cookie, the server can check that he created the token and that it is still valid. "State" information, like  what you selected on the website can be held on client side.

Comment: @Heinzlmaen Exactly... Looking at most of these answers, I came to realize that people don't actually know what they're talking about.

Answer (score 531):

HTTP is stateless. In order to authorize you, you have to "sign" every single request you're sending to server.

**Token authentication**

- A request to the server is signed by a "token" - usually it means setting specific HTTP headers, however, they can be sent in any part of the HTTP request (POST body, etc.)
- Pros:

  - You can authorize only the requests you wish to authorize. (Cookies - even the authorization cookie are sent for every single request.)
  - Immune to XSRF (Short example of XSRF - I'll send you a link in email that will look like `<img src="http://bank.example?withdraw=1000&to=myself" />`, and if you're logged in via cookie authentication to `bank.example`, and `bank.example` doesn't have any means of XSRF protection, I'll withdraw money from your account simply by the fact that your browser will trigger an authorized GET request to that url.) Note there are anti forgery measure you can do with cookie-based authentication - but you have to implement those.
  - Cookies are bound to a single domain. A cookie created on the domain `foo.example` can't be read by the domain `bar.example`, while you can send tokens to any domain you like. This is especially useful for single page applications that are consuming multiple services that are requiring authorization - so I can have a web app on the domain `myapp.example` that can make authorized client-side requests to `myservice1.example` and to `myservice2.example`.
- Cons:

  - You have to store the token somewhere; while cookies are stored "out of the box". The locations that comes to mind are localStorage (con: the token is persisted even after you close browser window), sessionStorage (pro: the token is discarded after you close browser window, con: opening a link in a new tab will render that tab anonymous) and cookies (Pro: the token is discarded after you close the browser window. If you use a session cookie you will be authenticated when opening a link in a new tab, and you're immune to XSRF since you're ignoring the cookie for authentication, you're just using it as token storage. Con: cookies are sent out for every single request. If this cookie is not marked as https only, you're open to man in the middle attacks.)
  - It is slightly easier to do XSS attack against token based authentication (i.e. if I'm able to run an injected script on your site, I can steal your token; however, cookie based authentication is not a silver bullet either - while cookies marked as http-only can't be read by the client, the client can still make requests on your behalf that will automatically include the authorization cookie.)
  - Requests to download a file, which is supposed to work only for authorized users, requires you to use File API. The same request works out of the box for cookie-based authentication.

**Cookie authentication**

- A request to the server is always signed in by authorization cookie.
- Pros:

  - Cookies can be marked as "http-only" which makes them impossible to be read on the client side. This is better for XSS-attack protection.
  - Comes out of the box - you don't have to implement any code on the client side.
- Cons:

  - Bound to a single domain. (So if you have a single page application that makes requests to multiple services, you can end up doing crazy stuff like a reverse proxy.)
  - Vulnerable to XSRF. You have to implement extra measures to make your site protected against cross site request forgery.
  - Are sent out for every single request, (even for requests that don't require authentication).

Overall, I'd say tokens give you better flexibility, (since you're not bound to single domain). The downside is you have to do quite some coding by yourself.

Comment: Thanks @ondrej-svejdar. It is by far the best answer! I would only argue with "quite some coding" part. There is good number of libraries available for pretty much any language. So unless you really want to know mechanics of JWT implementation there is no need to start from scratch.

Comment: `Are send out for every single request` Tokens are send for every request too

Comment: @EugenKonkov no. not necessearly. Only if you add the header. cookies are sent from browser if you want or if you don't want

Comment: Hi, I was wondering how cookie based authentication is vulnerable to CSRF. The Ajax cross site request will be preflighted by an OPTIONS request to get the CORS headers. If the domain is not allowed by the CORS headers, the actual CSRF attack will fail?

Comment: @Silver - attacker is not limited to ajax request. He can use html tags like <img src="malicious code here" ../> for emulating GET or <form ...> to emulate POST.

Comment: "Token authentication is immune to CSRF": based on which principle exactly do you make that claim? Since when cookies are an absolute requirement to execute a successful CSRF attack? If you click through a link that I sent you over Email, and your browser processes it, why does it matter if authentication was done with a cookie, Local Storage or resides in RAM?

Comment: @Zack - it does matter. Problem with cookies is they're appended to request by browser automatically. Tokens on the other hand are appended to XHR request by javascript. It is impossible for evildomain.com to get access to local storage for mysite.com (btw. I don't recommend local storage as a place to store tokens) or to ram (I assume you mean javascript variable here containing the token) because the variable is sandboxed in different browser window.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar The problem with token is that it can be stolen (unlike http only cookie). If you use http-only token + csrf token no one can impersonate You, even after XSRF (because csrf token should be bound to auth). If You use token and You got XSS'ed there is no hope.

Comment: @user2029276 Auth token are stolen only by XSS. If you have XSS, your XSRF token can also be stolen.

Comment: @FranklinYu But if You have token You can do everything, and You have XSRF token, You still cannot do much.

Comment: @FranklinYu Also if You post data to server by something else than forms (json), even if attacker has Your XSRF token he cannot do anything on Your behalf.

Comment: @user2029276 We assume that the target website already has XSS vulnerability, right? Then why can’t the attacker send same-origin AJAX request by XSS?

Comment: How about hidden field authentication?

Comment: There are more cons to tokens. No easy ability to invalidate tokens.

Comment: `crazy stuff like a reverse proxy.` Overall, great answer, but I feel this part is somewhat misleading. Reverse proxying an API underneath a single URL endpoint is not crazy, and sometimes required (had to once for a SPA website to support IE9 clients). Having a separate endpoint for your API is great for spreading load, especially in a SPA website, or scenario where your API is heavily used by other applications. Labeling reverse proxy as "crazy stuff" is a tad much.

Comment: This is indeed a well thought out answer! Thank you.
For those who are planing to use cookies, we can use following approach to mitigate CSRF attacks: 
we can create a cookie with a name `XSRF-TOKEN` in the backend, then front end can read that and include in every request header. So that backend can validate that. Please refer: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#cross-site-request-forgery-xsrf-protection for more details.

Comment: Just want to clarify that, in the example of a con for cookies that they can't be shared across different domains to consume separate services, this is not 100% accurate depending on the nature of the service... because they CAN be shared across different subdomains of the parent domain.

Comment: `Vulnerable to XSRF. You have to implement extra measures to make your site protected against cross site request forgery.` - this is not true. SameSite=Lax is the default value, which means by default, XSRF cannot happen with cookies.

Comment: @Silver The OPTIONS request, aka. pre-flight request is only for "non standard" HTTP requests, ie. requests that could only have been sent via Javascript. These are usually PUT/DELETE, where as GET/POST (if using standard headers) are standard and don't use preflight. With GET, the browser can't view the response due to the same origin policy (unless CORS allowed it), and because it's safe, it doesn't update anything on the server (assuming the devs designed it well), so CSRF attacks are useless with GET requests. That means it's pretty much just POST requests that are a problem.

Comment: @Silver this article explains how to do a CSRF attack, which is the best way to learn about CORS/SOP:
https://medium.com/gitconnected/simulating-a-csrf-attack-part-1-5ec8b0f8b152?sk=b3a72bec0891b9d4641729330015ea87

Answer (score 69):

**For Googlers**:

- DO NOT mix **statefulness** with **state transfer mechanisms**

**STATEFULNESS**

- **Stateful** = save authorization info on server side, this is the traditional way
- **Stateless** = save authorization info on client side, along with a signature to ensure integrity

**MECHANISMS**

- **Cookie** = a special header with special treatment (access, storage, expiration, security, auto-transfer) by browsers
- **Custom Headers** = e.g. `Authorization`, are just headers without any special treatment, client has to manage all aspects of the transfer
- **Other**. Other transfer mechanisms may be utilized, e.g. query string was a choice to transfer auth ID for a while but was abandoned for its insecurity

**STATEFULNESS COMPARISON**

- "Stateful authorization" means the server stores and maintains user authorization info on server, making authorizations part of the application state
- This means client only need to keep an "auth ID" and the server can read auth detail from its database
- This implies that server keeps a pool of active auths (users that are logged in) and will query this info for every request
- "Stateless authorization" means the server does not store and maintain user auth info, it simply does not know which users are signed in, and rely on the client to produce auth info
- Client will store complete auth info like who you are (user ID), and possibly permissions, expiration time, etc., this is more than just auth ID, so it is given a new name **token**
- Obviously client cannot be trusted, so auth data is stored along with a signature generated from `hash(data + secret key)`, where secret key is only known to server, so the integrity of token data can be verified
- Note that token mechanism merely ensures integrity, but not confidentiality, client has to implement that
- This also means for every request client has to submit a complete token, which incurs extra bandwidth

**MECHANISM COMPARISON**

- "Cookie" is just a header, but with some preloaded operations on browsers
- Cookie can be set by server and auto-saved by client, and will auto-send for same domain
- Cookie can be marked as `httpOnly` thus prevent client JavaScript access
- Preloaded operations may not be available on platforms other than browsers (e.g. mobile), which may lead to extra efforts
- "Custom headers" are just custom headers without preloaded operations
- Client is responsible to receive, store, secure, submit and update the custom header section for each requests, this may help prevent some simple malicious URL embedding

**SUM-UP**

- There is no magic, auth state has to be stored somewhere, either at server or client
- You may implement stateful/stateless with either cookie or other custom headers
- When people talk about those things their default mindset is mostly: stateless = token + custom header, stateful = auth ID + cookie; these are NOT the only possible options
- They have pros and cons, but even for encrypted tokens you should not store sensitive info

Answer (score 35):

- Tokens need to be stored somewhere (local/session storage or cookies)
- Tokens can expire like cookies, but you have more control
- Local/session storage won't work across domains, use a marker cookie
- Preflight requests will be sent on each CORS request
- When you need to stream something, use the token to get a signed request
- It's easier to deal with XSS than XSRF
- The token gets sent on every request, watch out its size
- If you store confidential info, encrypt the token
- JSON Web Tokens can be used in OAuth
- Tokens are not silver bullets, think about your authorization use cases carefully

http://blog.auth0.com/2014/01/27/ten-things-you-should-know-about-tokens-and-cookies/

http://blog.auth0.com/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/

Comment: It's not clear if your points are for Cookies or Tokens, which way round are they?

Comment: I don't understand why you "have more control" over tokens than you do over cookies.

Comment: @onsmith From what I understand there is more than single bullet point here. Firstly, cookie is sent with every request. Sending tokens is triggered by javascript code. They are not sent automatically. Also, in accordance to the [rfc section 4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#page-8) looks like JWT is designd as a container used for transferring security claims based between parties. Which provides more granular control as well as enables ability to generate authentication tokens for 3rd party with set of permissions allowing them to use them on your behalf.

Answer (score 12):

I believe that there is some confusion here.  The significant difference between cookie based authentication and what is now possible with [HTML5 Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) is that browsers are built to send cookie data whenever they are requesting resources from the domain that set them.  You can't prevent that without turning off cookies.  Browsers *do not send data from Web Storage unless code in the page sends it*.  And pages can only access data that they stored, not data stored by other pages.

So, a user worried about the way that their cookie data might be used by Google or Facebook might turn off cookies.  But, they have less reason to turn off Web Storage (until the advertisers figure a way to use that as well).

So, that's the difference between cookie based and token based, the latter uses Web Storage.

Answer (score 6):

Token based authentication is stateless, server need not store user information in the session. This gives  ability to scale application without worrying where the user has logged in.  There is web Server Framework  affinity for cookie based while that is not an issue with token based. So the same token can be used for fetching a secure resource from a domain other than the one we are logged in which avoids another uid/pwd authentication.

Very good article here:

http://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs

Answer (score 5):

Use Token when...

Federation is desired. For example, you want to use one provider (Token Dispensor) as the token issuer, and then use your api server as the token validator. An app can authenticate to Token Dispensor, receive a token, and then present that token to your api server to be verified. (Same works with Google Sign-In. Or Paypal. Or Salesforce.com. etc)

Asynchrony is required. For example, you want the client to send in a request, and then store that request somewhere, to be acted on by a separate system "later". That separate system will not have a synchronous connection to the client, and it may not have a direct connection to a central token dispensary. a JWT can be read by the asynchronous processing system to determine whether the work item can and should be fulfilled at that later time. This is, in a way, related to the Federation idea above. Be careful here, though: JWT expire. If the queue holding the work item does not get processed within the lifetime of the JWT, then the claims should no longer be trusted.

Cient Signed request is required. Here, request is signed by client using his private key and server would validate using already registered public key of the client.

Answer (score 3):

One of the primary differences is that cookies are subject to Same Origin Policy whereas tokens are not. This creates all kinds of down stream effects.

Since cookies are only sent to and from a particular host that host must bear the burden of authenticating the user and the user must create an account with security data with that host in order to be verifiable.

Tokens on the other hand are issued and are not subject to same origin policy. The issuer can be literally anybody and it is up to the host to decide which issuers to trust. An issuer like Google and Facebook is typically well trusted so a host can shift the burden of authenticating the user (including storing all user security data) to another party and the user can consolidate their personal data under a specific issuer and not have to remember a bunch of different passwords for each host they interact with.

This allows for single sign on scenarios that reduce overall friction in the user experience. In theory the web also becomes more secure as specialised identity providers emerge to provide auth services instead of having every ma and pa website spinning up their own, likely half baked, auth systems. And as these providers emerge the cost of providing secure web resources for even very basic resources trends towards zero.

So in general tokens reduce the friction and costs associated with providing authentication and shifts the burden of the various aspects of a secure web to centralised parties better able to both implement and maintain security systems.

Answer (score -1):

Session cookies rely on you having a personal secret shared with a database on the other end that stores the fact that you are logged in. There is nothing fancy here, just a passphrase to identify what your session is, though the details can vary.

An auth token uses fancy cryptography to eliminate the need of a database that stores your login state, by issuing a document with what you are allowed to do until which date, with a signature by a given provider.

To give an analogy, a cookie is like a membership card, where the reception checking it has to phone in or query a database to check that you are a member. While an auth token is like a check with a signature and an expiration date. The security then comes from the signature based on the assumption that it is difficult to fake, without having to directly ask the issuer.

In both cases, those deal with authorization, not authentication. Anyone with the membership card or the check gets the access right, they don't prove who you are, just that you have the right to the resource you ask for. Because of this, they have to be carefully guarded against theft, and this is especially true of the auth token which is harder to revoke.

Comment: You're talking about JWTs. Not all tokens need to be self-signed and can act exactly as a session ID