# How do I authenticate my user on a custom backend using my firebase JWT?

Tags: http, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

I successfully authenticated my user with my firebase app in the browser. Now I want my custom backend to know that the user is authenticated.

How do I go about this? Can I tell the client to include the firebase JWT in every request to my backend, so that the backend knows the user is logged in? (This is necessary so that the backend will not redirect a logged-in user to the login page, for example.)

**Background Research:**

The [firebase authentication docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) explain how to get the firebase token, send it to your custom backend, and then do something on the backend with the user data. That's fine for an XHR request, where you can tell the browser to include the token as a header. I don't understand how to get the browser to include the token in a normal HTTP request to the server, like when the user opens a new tab and navigates to the admin panel at `https://example.com/admin`.

This is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30061307/jwt-how-to-handle-get-requests-when-user-opens-a-new-tab?rq=1), but I didn't understand the answer (or at least how I could apply it to my use case).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how the good guys at [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/introduction/) explain it:

> Whenever the user wants to access a protected route or resource, the user agent should send the JWT, typically in the Authorization header using the Bearer schema. The content of the header should look like the following:
>
> **Authorization: Bearer <token>**
>
> This is a stateless authentication mechanism as the user state is never saved in server memory. The server's protected routes will check for a valid JWT in the Authorization header, and if it's present, the user will be allowed to access protected resources.

Comment: Okay, cool. But what I don't understand is: how do I tell the user agent to set the JWT in the Authorization header for all requests made to http://example.com?

Comment: I guess something like this:
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); xhr.open('GET', 'http:example.com'); xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

Comment: But that doesn't set the Authorization header for subsequent HTTP requests, right? To be clear, this is my use case: User logs in. Now user opens new tab and goes to http://example.com/admin. When the user logged in, I want to tell the browser to include the token in the Authorization header in my subsequent requests to http://example.com, so that the token will be included when the user navigates to http://example.com/admin. Does this make sense? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to achieve [SSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on)? One way is to store the JWT as a cookie. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30061307/jwt-how-to-handle-get-requests-when-user-opens-a-new-tab)'s a solution.