# Django: JWT: will it allow to keep user logged in even i open the domain in new tab

Tags: django, jwt

I am creating a webapp and mobile app using DJango. I am using DRF to generate rest api.

I will be using JWT token authentication for users to login in. I will passing the token in Authorization header through javascript and not by cookie

Assuming some one logs in to my domain (eg: sample.com) in a browser, now if i open sample.com in new tab will I have to again login or browser will remember that i have already logged in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JWT: how to handle GET requests when user opens a new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30061307/jwt-how-to-handle-get-requests-when-user-opens-a-new-tab)

Answer (score -2):

You must store the JWT Token returned by the server in local HTML5 client storage or a cookie to be able to access the same in different browser tabs. You can set the cookie to expire on window close. Note that by 'cookie' I'm not at all referring to the session cookie but just some cookie that your client side JS app may create on its own. Unless you store the token somewhere, the other tabs won't be able to access it and the user will eventually see himself logged out on the other tab.