# Laravel Sanctum API Token Security

Tags: laravel-sanctum

Hello great people of SO!

I hope you all have a great day!

**First of all, I'm new to SPA, and I'm sorry if my english is bad
But I will try my best to explain what issue I have right now**

I'm creating a simple SPA that use Sanctum API Token as Authentication and Vue as Front

After creating simple Auth mechanism (such: Route guard, errors, etc) of this SPA, a simple thought comes to my mind

> What if I copy a token, then insert it to another browser, will the server Authenticate me?

Steps to produce:

- First, I login to Brave browser, and server return the Authorization token, the token stored inside Brave localStorage, and Front-end part redirect me to '/home' route, everything works normal like simple authentication
- Then, I opened Firefox browser, I put token and token_value inside localStorage, which I got before from logging in with Brave browser
- I visited '/home' route, which is only for Authenticated users, and the server accept me.

I cannot find in documentation about this matter

How to solve this matter?

Comment: It's normal. what did you mean? your token is authenticate one time.

Comment: It's just like asking if someone copies username & password ,will the server authenticate? tokens are meant for authorization and they work like that. If you want to restrict it to browser which was used to authenticate, maybe setting cookies can help,which are per browser

Answer (score 2):

The Laravel docs state, "You should not use API tokens to authenticate your own first-party SPA. Instead, use Sanctum's built-in SPA authentication features".

You might want to read more between Tokens and Cookies for authentication here.
[Token Authentication vs. Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000835/token-authentication-vs-cookies)

You would be authenticated anytime you send a request with a valid token. Doesn't matter which browser. It works on any medium that is able to make a request.

If it's a SPA, use Sanctum SPA authentication mechanisms.

Not sure if this answers your questions.